# Gorm create only if entry does not exists

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have the following structs:

```
type Project struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title       string
    Description string
    Skills      []Skill `gorm:"many2many:project_skills;"`
}

type Skill struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}
```

this is how I create the project (and then Gorm creates automatically the skills):

```
create := rs.Db().Create(&project)
```

there is a simple way through gorm to create skills only if there is no entry with the same name?, and if there is, return the existing one.
so I will get an array of skills, the new one, and old ones.
I hope I managed to explain myself.

Comment: Did you try `FirstOrCreate()`?

Comment: @AbdullahI forgat to say that I am creating only the project and Gorm creates skills for me. there is a way gorm can do it automatically, or I need to create first the skills and then attached them to the project?

Comment: @NirBerko You would be required to add all the skills once during the initialization of the application. So that you can add it to the `Project`.

Comment: @iamvinitk so the only way is to add the skills before adding the project, and then relate them to the skills. so there is no way to Gorm to do this automatically with some struct options?